# 'smtplib.SMTPReciepientsRefused' : The reciepient address 789 is not a valid RFC-5321 address

Tags: python-3.x

In my Python code, I am facing an error which says 'smtplib.SMTPReciepientsRefused'. I have checked it twice but not able to figure out the holes. Can anyone help me out to fill them out?

```
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
import smtplib
def send_email(email,X,Y,X1,Y1,location,holder_name):
    from_email="abc@gmail.com"
    from_password="abc123"
    to_email=email

    subject="DNA Record"
    message="Your Data Has Been Recorded successfully"

    msg=MIMEText(message,'html')
    msg['Subject']=subject
    msg['To']=to_email
    msg['From']=from_email

    gmail=smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com',587)
    gmail.ehlo()
    gmail.starttls()
    gmail.login(from_email,from_password)
    gmail.send_message(msg)
```

Comment: Please add a full traceback of the error...

Comment: Thanks Bill armstrong .. but i have got my doubt cleared .